Why are small objects melting into the surface?
I have been working on a wine bottle render for some time, and i did not find a better way to create a silver gel texture on top of the label other than moddeling the text and illustration as a very thin object and parenting it to the surface of the label. When I am checking the viewport display to see the results, everything seems normal.
Viewport_display

When i start rendering, the gel is absorbed partially by the label it is attached to, and i could not find any solutions to this problem.
The objects do not have any kind of modifiers.

Has anyone encountered this before? I really need some help =(((

hello if your label has a Subdivision Surface make sure that the viewport and render levels are the same? If it's not the problem maybe share your file?

Hi! Sorry, forgot to post it: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Lx8PZxm1w1MdvGd3ymyiWQMgqlUM3r4Q?usp=drive_link
The objects do not have any modifiers applied to them, so that is not the case :(

your link asks for an authorization    ;)

Man, I think i managed the deal, sorry again ;D
Sometimes when duplicating objects and moving them to create another set, the duplicate still ends in the same place if you cancel the move operation. The duplicate had a solidify modifier on it, which was visible in the render but not the viewport display. My mistake)

oh ok, nice that you've found the problem   ;)

The render Camera has its own depth resolution, which can be different from the viewport Camera depth resolution.
If the resolution is poor you get Z fighting between surfaces close to each other.
To increase the depth resolution you can try to reduce the gap between clip start and clip end, enclosing only the area of the useful render objects (including environment, if present).

